# Uploading files with Restful interface

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to upload a file (like image file) into a Restful server like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------4ebf00fbcf09" --data-binary @sample.jpg http://localhost:3000/test
```

However, the request doesn't seem to be processed by my Restful server resource.

- How to upload a file (small and large ) to a Spring web resource
- Is the "attachment" type upload is totally different than uploading through a simple Form upload?
- If the Content-Type: `multipart/form-data; boundary=...` how can I get the actual content type, like: "image/jpeg" etc.

This is the code snippet for my web resource:

```
          try 
          {
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
            FileItemIterator fileIterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
            while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = fileIterator.next();
                byte[] content = ByteStreams.toByteArray(item.openStream());
            }
             ...
          }
```

My concern is the type of client-side upload that the code can support, I use Rest Console Chrome plugin and upload attachment which works with this code, but the cURL code above is not working.

Also, what are the possible `FileItemIterator`s that can be retrieved from a `HttpServletRequest`?

Here is the complete code of my restful web service resource: http://bit.ly/QwTOLw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the Spring manual's section on [Spring's multipart (file upload) support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart). Make sure you have a `MultipartResolver` bean declared in your context and consider mapping the file as a `MultipartFile` in a form-backing object so you can have Spring handle resolving/reading the multipart data itself (rather than trying to parse the FileItemIterator, ServletFileUpload etc yourself).